# Taking the cross product of an unknown matrix with an unknown function in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I would like sympy to confirm that, given the equation:

$$
r'(t) = A \times r(t)
$$

(i.e. "the derivative of an unknown function r is the cross product of an unknown matrix A with r"), it follows that:

$$
r''(t) = A \times r'(t)
$$

(i.e. "the second derivative of r is the cross product of A with the first derivative of r").

From the documentation it seems like I want to use `MatrixSymbol` for `A`, but `MatrixSymbol` doesn't define `cross`:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import *
r = Function('r')(t) 
A = MatrixSymbol('A', 4, 4)  # dummy dimensions

Derivative(A.cross(r))
```

gives me:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-4c8dc7c142cf> in <module>
      4 A = MatrixSymbol('A', 4, 4)
      5 
----> 6 Derivative(A.cross(r))

AttributeError: 'MatrixSymbol' object has no attribute 'cross'
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: I guess what you need is not `MatrixSymbol`, but `Matrix`. It has a [cross](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixBase.cross) method.

Comment: What do you mean by cross product? Generally the cross-product is between two 3D vectors rather than two matrices. Your example uses a 4x4 matrix and a scalar function. Do you mean a matrix product between say a 4x4 matrix and a 4x1 "column vector" where the vector is a function of `t` but the matrix is constant with respect to `t`?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin: Yes, you're right, I think I want `A` and `r(t)` to be vectors of the same dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SymPy's vector class is completely separate from the Matrix class which can be confusing if you're used to thinking of a vector as a particular kind of matrix:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/vector/index.html

I'll demonstrate how to do this with the vector class. This can be done more compactly but I'm spelling it out in detail:

```
In [23]: from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D 
    ...: N = CoordSys3D('N')                                                                                                                   

In [24]: a1, a2, a3 = symbols('a1:4')                                                                                                          

In [25]: r1, r2, r3 = [ri(t) for ri in symbols('r1:4', cls=Function)]                                                                          

In [26]: A = a1*i + a2*j + a3*k                                                                                                                

In [27]: r = r1*i + r2*j + r3*k                                                                                                                

In [28]: A                                                                                                                                     
Out[28]: a1*N.i + a2*N.j + a3*N.k

In [29]: r                                                                                                                                     
Out[29]: (r1(t))*N.i + (r2(t))*N.j + (r3(t))*N.k

In [30]: (A.cross(r.diff(t))).diff(t) == A.cross(r.diff(t, 2))                                                                                 
Out[30]: True
```

Comment: Thanks. It sounds like it's not possible to get sympy to treat the two vectors as a black box of unknown dimensions -- is that correct? Also, should 26 and 27 be `N.i`, `N.j`, etc? I get an error about "cross is undefined for Add" as written

Comment: Looks like I missed out `i, j, k = N.base_vectors()`. I don't think that there is a "vector symbol" analogue of `MatrixSymbol` that you could use for this sort of thing.